# How do you quit out of a Flashpunk AS3 game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

So i am making a game using the Flashpunk framework for AS3, and i can't seem to figure out how to terminate the program execution when the user clicks an exit button. I have tried using both `System.exit(0)` and `fscommand("quit")`, but neither of these work in the release build (the former only works in debug mode, the latter doesn't work at all). Does anyone know how to code an exit button in Flashpunk?

Here is my code:

```
import flash.system.*;
public class Story extends World 
{
    var btnDone:Button = new Button(FP.screen.width * 9 / 10, FP.screen.height * 9 / 10, btnDonePressed, "End", { size: 50, color: 0xFFFFFF } );
    btnDone.setCentered(true);
    add(btnDone);
}
private function btnDonePressed():void
{
    System.exit(0);
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Comment: What are you publishing this game as? a SWF in the browser? Standalone EXE/.app? AIR? If you're targetting AIR, fscommand is a quite out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fscommand("quit")` on your button. But to make it work you need to import the fscommand at the top of your code `import flash.system.fscommand;`.

Also you can use `System.exit(0)` by importing `import flash.system.System;` at the top of your code.

Comment: Please reread the original question. I have already tried both of those and neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting your Flashpunk game to Adobe AIR, then you should try:

`NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(); //Small "n" on the second nativeApplication`

Reference: [Air equivalence for fscommand("quit")](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/421777?start=0&tstart=0)